# How to fix the vulnerabilities in npm if I cannot upgrade the major version of dependency?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, npm, audit

I have a high risk vulnerability from `npm audit --production`. This is dependency of snowflake-sdk. But I checked [snowflake github](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs) it has     `"requestretry": "^6.0.0"` in the package.json which mean it doesn't support requestretry 7.0.0. Is there any other way to fix this vulnerability? What if I upgrade requestretry to 7.0.0?

[image]

I am very new to npm and javascript, any help is appreciated!

Comment: [This issue is already being discussed](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/issues/268) but it's up the repo owners to deal with it, not you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think snowflake just fixed the issue:

```
"requestretry": "^7.0.1",
```

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-nodejs/blob/master/package.json